# AlertDialog Builder Control Access

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Custom AlertDialog.Builder but I couldn't reach the EditText.

This is my DEFAULT Class;

```
        AlertDialog.Builder Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater Inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        View AddCategory = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_new, null);

        final EditText etCategoryName = (EditText) AddCategory.findViewById(R.id.btnAddCategory);

        Builder.setView(AddCategory)
        .setTitle("Add Category")
        .setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Time Today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                Today.setToNow();

                //This code has error !...
                String CategoryName = etCategoryName.getText().toString();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }); 

        Builder.show();
```

This
String CategoryName = etCategoryName.getText().toString();

This is my Costum AlertDialog layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAddCategoryName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/AddCategoryName"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etAddCategoryName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvAddCategoryName"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvAddCategoryName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvAddCategoryName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/CategoryName"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Please help me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
final EditText etCategoryName = (EditText) AddCategory.findViewById(R.id.etAddCategoryName);
```

In Your xml file your editText id is `etAddCategoryName` and in your java file you initialize different name (btnAddCategory).

So please change `btnAddCategory` to `etAddCategoryName` .

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is occurred because you are passing button id instead of edittext id

Please Write below line of code

```
final EditText etCategoryName = (EditText) AddCategory.findViewById(R.id.etAddCategoryName);
```

instead of

```
final EditText etCategoryName = (EditText) AddCategory.findViewById(R.id.btnAddCategory);
```

Answer (score 0):

If Seems like you mistyped the EditText id, you put R.id.btnAddCategory and seems like it should be R.id.etAddCategoryName.